# compare changing arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to figure this it but I don't find the solution. I have two arrays like this

```
var oldList = [
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-61,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-483,13","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-57,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-50,00","desc":"item1"}
]

var newList = [
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-61,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-483,13","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-57,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-50,00","desc":"item1"}
]
```

The newList array will update all the time, and I need items from newList to be added to oldList, and as you can see sometimes there is multiple items with the exact same data like `{"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},` in newList, anyone have any idea about this?

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention

newList will also remove the oldest items after some time but they should still be in oldList.

Comment: [Give this a shot](https://lodash.com/docs#matches)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of each item's age, then give each an id value that's equal to the seconds since epoc of the time when they were received.

```
var newItem = {date="2015-06-30", amount: "-1 088,00", desc: "item1"};
var currentDate = new Date();
newItem.id = currentDate.getTime();
```

Now: `newItem = {"id": 1435689401404, "date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"}`

This allows you to iterate through the new array and move the item with the lowest id value (which will be the oldest item) to the old array.

Comment: the problem is that I get the items from an external api that doesn't have id's

Comment: @Stellan you could just keep track of them by the date you receive the item from the API. As soon as you receive an item, add the id field to the object with the value `(new Date()).getTime()` (number of seconds since EPOC).

Comment: new items in newList should be added to oldList, and the newList is from an api, which list did you mean I should add the timestamp to?

Comment: @Stellan you should add the timestamp as a value for new items taken from the API and added to newList. This allows you to iterate through newList and place the item with the smallest timestamp in the oldList each time a new item comes from the API.

Comment: @Stellan you already are storing two lists: oldList and newLIst. That's all you need.

Comment: the newList was more an example of what the data looks like coming from the api, would there be any way to do this without storing the api list?

Comment: @Stellan do what? So now there is no newList? You just want to store all of the items that come in through the API in oldList? I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: no I want to store the items that doesn't exist in oldList from newList which is the list I get from the api.
And it would be best if I don't have to store two separate lists in my db.
For example say I have about 100 items in oldList and every time I call the api I will get maybe 110 items, and after some time the list in the api will remove the oldest items to still show about 110 every time.

Comment: did you understand what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I came to understand, you can try this. This function will add fields `newList` a `oldList` except repeated elements.

```js
var oldList = [
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-61,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-483,13","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-57,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-50,00","desc":"item1"}
];

var newList = [
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-30","amount":"-1 008,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-61,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-483,13","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-29","amount":"-57,00","desc":"item2"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-50,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-20,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-20,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-20,00","desc":"item1"},
    {"date":"2015-06-28","amount":"-20,00","desc":"item1"}
];
  
newList.forEach(function(item){
    var itemLine = [item.date, item.amount, item.desc];
    var exists = oldList.some(function(oldItem){
        var old = [oldItem.date, oldItem.amount, oldItem.desc];
        if(old.join() === itemLine.join()) return true;
        return false
    });
    !exists && oldList.push(item)
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(oldList, 0, 3) + "<pre>")
```

Comment: Thanks, only repeated items missing then. any idea for that?

Comment: In this example the elements of `newList` are added to `oldList`, ignoring repeated in both arrays. If you explain to me the problem or make an example about this would help.

Comment: newList is items from an api that I want to store in my db = oldList, newList will update all the time and will sometimes have repeated items.
So basically I want to store everything new from the api to oldList.
And the items in oldList will be get an extra value once the user has verified it so the items in oldList shouldn't be overwritten.